# ngx-icon-picker: How to reset default value to blank?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, npm-package

In our angular project, we need to integrate icon picker dropdown. To integrate it, we used ngx-icon-picker npm library. But when we added it, we saw that when we reload the page it sets a default value. But we want it a blank field like normal input tag with placeholder. Can anyone help us to fix that?

We want like this:

[image]

This is ts file:

```
`import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-icon-picker',
  templateUrl: './icon-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./icon-picker.component.scss']
})
export class IconPickerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output()
  selectedIcon = new EventEmitter<string>();
  
  icon = '';

  fallbackIcon = '';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  onIconPickerSelect(icon: string) {
    this.icon = icon;
    this.selectedIcon.emit(this.icon);
  }
}`
```

This is HTML:

```
`<div class="relative h-14" style="margin-bottom: 1.34375em">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Select icon..." id="icon-input" 
   class="h-full w-full px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md hover:border-black transition-all duration-300 my-input-class"
          [ipButtonStyleClass]="'border-2 border-primary rounded-md'"
          [ipDivSearchStyleClass]="'control'"
          [ipInputSearchStyleClass]="''"
          [ipIconVerticalPadding]="'8px'"
          [ipIconHorizontalPadding]="'8px'"
          [ipIconSize]="'20px'"
          [ipWidth]="'280px'"
          [ipIconPack]="['fa5']"  [iconPicker]="icon"
          [ipFallbackIcon]="fallbackIcon"
          [ipPosition]="'bottom'" (iconPickerSelect)="onIconPickerSelect($event)"  [(ngModel)]="icon"/>
  <button id="icon-button" class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pl-4 pr-4 border-l border-gray-300 "
          [ipButtonStyleClass]="'border-2 border-primary rounded-md'"
          [ipDivSearchStyleClass]="'control'"
          [ipInputSearchStyleClass]="''"
          [ipIconVerticalPadding]="'8px'"
          [ipIconHorizontalPadding]="'8px'"
          [ipIconSize]="'20px'"
          [ipWidth]="'280px'"
          [ipIconPack]="['fa5']"  [iconPicker]="icon"
          [ipFallbackIcon]="fallbackIcon"
          [ipPosition]="'bottom'" (iconPickerSelect)="onIconPickerSelect($event)" >
    <i [class]="icon"></i>
  </button>
</div>`
```

Currently we are getting:

[image]